# Need to draw vertical lines in expand/collapse in p-tree

Tags: css, angular, primeng, boost-propertytree

I am using p-tree from prime-ng, and need to draw the vertical lines(Highlighted with red pen) via css like this:

[image]

I have done the rest part and working fine, only vertical lines need to draw. My Implementation is looking something like below:

[image]

I just need to draw vertical lines below + and - icons.
Kindly Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by adding the following style:

```
::ng-deep .p-tree .p-treenode-children .p-treenode {
  border-left: 1px dashed black;
}
```

It might require some tinkering if you made some changes to the styling, maybe add `margin-left` to move the border a bit.

You can see a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treeselection-demo-k2pwq4?file=src/app/app.component.css).